# How would I install Google Sign-In on a Swift macOS app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoapods, google-signin

When I try the normal way through Cocoapods:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :osx, '10.13'

target '1072 Scouting' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Google/SignIn'
  # Pods for scouting1072-mac
end
```

I get the error:

```
[!] The platform of the target `1072 Scouting` (macOS 10.13) is not compatible with `Google/SignIn (3.1.0)`, which does not support `osx`.
```

How would I install Google Sign-In so I can have similar functionality to an install on an iOS project?

Comment: Hi atirit, did you ever figure it out?